# Creating variables based on the number of correct answers in four binary variables

Tags: syntax, spss

I have four binary variables that ask participants if they think the statement is true or false:

`quiz1`, `quiz2`, `quiz3`, `quiz4`.

Now based on the number of correct answers of these four quizzes, I'd like to create new variables:

`noCorrect`, `oneCorrect`, `twoCorrect`, `threeCorrect`, `fourCorrect`.

How do I go about doing so using SPSS SYNTAX? I assumed it would use `IF` and `COUNT`, and tried different things but wasn't able to get it work.
I'd very much appreciate any inputs based on your experiences.

Comment: What are you storing in the `quiz` variables ? The actual answers, or the Correct/Incorrect result ?

Comment: Please edit your post to add a few lines of data as example (can't suggest syntax solution without understanding the structure of your data).